# Regex: possible to match repeated patterns in openrefine?

Tags: openrefine

In openrefine I'm trying, for example, to get all the occurences of [aeio]+ in "abeadsabmoloei", in an array : ["a","ea","a","o","oei"]
Let's suppose we don't know the content of the string.
Is it possible with match function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match()` function is not made to find multiple instances of a pattern in the same string. This is why [a discussion is under way](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1296) to implement a `find()` or `findAll()` function. In the meantime, two lines of Python/Jython will do the trick:

```
import re
return re.findall(r"[aeio]+", value)
```

[image]